# How to add 0's infront with auto increment in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

My problem in fairly simple. I have a login system constructed using php, mysql databases, and ajax. Everything was working until today when I found a very potential problem that could completely confuse the system. Every single user in the database has a id that is automatically generated by setting auto-increment for the id column to give them a unique id. now my problem is that for example, my chat system, is trying to display all the users in the room. Well, the id for my first user is 1, and the id for the second user is 104. So, php extracts all the users id's from the database, which is stored in this format:
`user1id,user2id,user3id` and so on. But when php searches those id's for id #1 to see if it exists, it finds a 1 in id 104. That's where the problem starts. Sensing that the user is already in, php changes the record accordingly, and updates the user list to this: `04,1`. It was `104,1` before. Now, the script tries to locate the username for id #04, which doesn't exist. Therefore, a incorrect list of users in the room is given. Now, the most sensible solution to this I think is to add 0's infront of the shorter id's, so instead of `104,1`,it's `104,001`. But How exactly do I do that with auto increment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why you are searching for ids that way, but if you must do that, simply wrap your string with commas (`"104,1"` becomes `",104,1,"`) and search for `",1,"`. Or, [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) and use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array). And, if you are **storing** your users as a comma-separated list, NORMALIZE YOUR TABLES: use a junction table instead.

Comment: If your system thinks that 1 equals 104...

Comment: Consider separating your question into paragraphs to improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, but I found a solution. I would get the longest value in the array after explode, and use str_pad to add enough 0's to the end of every value in the array.

Answer (score 2):

When searching for users with a comma deliminated list, try using explode() function to turn the list into an array then doing the search using the in_array() function

Comment: As a side note, there is probably a better way of storing this information in the first place.

Comment: I've already used the explode(). But I didn't use in_array().That seems sensible. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: You used explode already? and you still managed to come up with the problem you posted? I would stongly suggest posting an extract of your current codes if you are still coming up with issues.

Comment: I can't answer my question yet, but I found a solution. I would get the longest value in the array after explode, and use str_pad to add enough 0's to the end of every value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are asking for by make the id field "zero-filled".

But there are many better approaches to this problem...